Steps to load env files in ADO pipeline for React project
What are the steps that I should follow to deploy my React project with the help of ADO pipeline YAML. I need help for ENV files.
In my local source project, I use {process.env.variablename} to load variables from env file and Create React App is used to create project hence I didn't add any dotenv package. Everything works fine in local and I see that variable contents are loaded from env file but in pipeline I followed below steps to load and I don't see that variables are loading from env files in my site but I see the env file getting copied into server. Why is it not loading? I have added my .env.development file under secure files section of library tab in ADO.
steps:
      - checkout: FoodApp

      - task: UseNode@1 
        inputs:
          version: '20.15.1'
          
      - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
        displayName: 'load env files'
        inputs:
          secureFile: '.env.development'

      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
          Contents: '.env.development'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FoodApp\'
          OverWrite: true
        displayName: 'copy .env.development to project root'
        
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'npm install dotenv'
        inputs:
          command: 'custom'
          customCommand: 'install dotenv'
          workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FoodApp\'

      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
           node -e "require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env.development' });"
          workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FoodApp\'
        displayName: 'Load environment variables from .env.development file'

      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
             Get-ChildItem -Path Env:* | Sort-Object -Property Name
        displayName: 'Display environment variables'
         
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'cache verify'
        inputs:
         command: 'custom'
         workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FoodApp\'
         customCommand: 'cache verify'


      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'npm clean'
        inputs:
          command: 'custom'
          workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FoodApp\'
          customCommand: 'rm -rf node_modules'

      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'npm install'
        inputs:
         command: 'install'
         workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FoodApp\'

      
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: 'Check Node.js version'
        inputs:
         script: 'node -v'
         workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FoodApp\'

   
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'run build'
        inputs:
           command: 'custom'
           workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\FoodApp\'
           customCommand: 'run build --mode development'
      
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy React files'
        inputs:
          sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/FoodApp/build' 
          Contents: '**/*'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/FoodApp'
          cleanTargetFolder: true
          
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy .env.development file'
        inputs:
          sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/FoodApp/'
          Contents: '.env.development'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/FoodApp'
          cleanTargetFolder: false


I have checked the YAML definition. And I noticed that you have set the development mode and copied the .env.development file to the target server.

Why is it not loading? I have added my .env.development file under secure files section of library tab in ADO.

You can check the following points:
1.With create react app, you need to prefix REACT_APP_ to the variable name.
For example:
REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:3000
REACT_APP_CUSTOMER=test

In your react app file, you can use the format: {process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE} to use the environment variable.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Adding Custom Environment Variables
2.You need to make sure that the .env.development file is located in the root of your project.
3.After deploying the files to your server, you need to restart the server and check if the changes are showed.
Here is my sample:
.env.development file
REACT_APP_CUSTOMER=test

js file
....
<p>Name : {process.env.REACT_APP_CUSTOMER}</p>
....

Files on the server:

Result:

Update:
Based on my test, React doesn't read environment variables at runtime, only at build time.
The cause of the issue can be that --mode development not force the npm run build to use the .env.development file.
By default, npm run build will read the env files with the following names: .env.production.local, .env.local, .env.production, .env.
You can remove the --mode development argument in the npm run build step and change the .env file name to .env.production.
Or you can use the package: dotenv-cli and define the .env file in the package.json file.
For example:
{
  ....
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
  ....
    "dotenv-cli": "7.4.2"

  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build:dev": "dotenv -e .env.development react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "dotenv -e .env.production react-scripts build",
  ......
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.2.0"
  }
}

Then you can run the command: npm run build:dev in the pipeline to force the npm run build command read the .env.development file.

When we deploy the changes the folder structure would be different right and above screen shot is local source code structure not after the deployment. In my local source i was able to load the content from env files and it works fine but i'm facing issue in after deployment using yaml ADO pipeline where my site is not reading content from env files. below is my structure after deployment. ---assets ---static ---.env.development ---asset-manifest.json ---favicon ---index ---manifest.json ---robots ---web

but how come other contents are working in my site ? only env file variables are not loading. If node_modules are not included then my entire site should break. and also i tried npm install in YAML pipeline that will do all the installation on my serve right? Correct me if I'm wrong as I'm new to this deployments pipeline

we use npm run build command to deploy the changes so that command will create build folder and we should use this one to target right ? hence in ado pipeline I'm targeting that folder as source . Please correct me if I'm wrong

@MrIsh Can you share what deployment server you are using?

Azure devops server used

What is a web hosting server?

IIS server is used

Can you try to do the following changes and have a try? 1. Change the .env.development to .env or .env.production 2. Try to remove the argument: --mode development in the npm run build step (directly run npm run build). Please refer to my update in the answer.

Thank you so much .Works fine now. I deleted all other env files and kept only .env and removed this argument as well --mode development

unable to accept as i have less reputation but appreciate your help

@MrIsh  Accepting an answer does not have reputation requirement. When you accept answer, this means that the answer can work for you. And it will be easier for other users to find the solution. You can refer to the steps in the ticket to accept: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235
